# How to make contenteditable div to allow only certain tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I'm using a contenteditable div.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div contenteditable="true"></div>

<button id="insert_strong">Strong!</button>

<button id="insert_italic">Italic</button>

<button id="insert_span">Span!</button>

<script>
  $("#insert_strong").click(function(){
      $("div").append('<strong>Strong text!</strong> ');
  });

  $("#insert_italic").click(function(){
      $("div").append('<i>Italic text!</i> ');
  });

  $("#insert_span").click(function(){
      $("div").append('<span>Span text!</span> ');
  });
</script>
```

Even if I remove the buttons, People can still paste any html tags by copy pasting from any website. I want people to be able to post only `<strong>` tags inside it, all other tags should be eliminated. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution. Here it is:

```js
$("#insert_strong").click(function(){
    $("div").append('<strong>Strong text!</strong> ');
    div_key_up("div");
});

$("#insert_italic").click(function(){
    $("div").append('<i>Italic text!</i> ');
    div_key_up("div");
});

$("#insert_span").click(function(){
    $("div").append('<span>Span text!</span> ');
    div_key_up("div");
});

function div_key_up(l)
{
  $(l).html(strip_tags($(l).html(), "<strong><br>"));
}

function strip_tags(input, allowed)
{
  allowed = (((allowed || '') + '')
  .toLowerCase()
  .match(/<[a-z][a-z0-9]*>/g) || [])
  .join('');
  var tags = /<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>/gi,
  commentsAndPhpTags = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->|<\?(?:php)?[\s\S]*?\?>/gi;
  return input.replace(commentsAndPhpTags, '')
  .replace(tags, function($0, $1)
  {
    return allowed.indexOf('<' + $1.toLowerCase() + '>') > -1 ? $0 : '';
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div contenteditable="true" onkeyup="div_key_up(this);"></div>

<button id="insert_strong">Strong!</button>

<button id="insert_italic">Italic</button>

<button id="insert_span">Span!</button>
```